# How to draw a line across 2 pictureboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm currently tasked to make a program to draw line between 2 pictures. in the future the line will be rotated but still connected as 1 line. for now trying to make the line connect between 2 pictures first. 
currently using 2 panels as the pictures and big picturebox set as transparent covering both of the panel as canvas for draw the lines but when doing test run the form are blank like in the picture. 
My question is.

1. How to fix this blank error? if this can be fixed then drawing the lines across pictures can be done on the big picturebox.
2. if cant. is there any other method to draw lines / connected pictures across 2 pictureboxes? thank you very much.

I dont know the keyword to search that error. I tried using picturebox & panels but the result are same.

Form with 2 panels as pictureboxes

[image: Form with 2 panels as pictureboxes]

big picturebox covering the panel

[image: big picturebox covering the panel]

blank error result

[image: blank error result]

edit. tried splitting the 1 big picturebox for 2 images. it works for the line drawing but the blank error for the buttons below is back.

[image: working picturebox but with blank error]

Comment: Are you just loading the pictures to the panels BackgroundImage property or some other method? If not, post your code for loading the images. Drawing to the picturebox should be done in the paint event using the e.Graphics.DrawLine() method. From what I remember though, pictureboxes are not transparent and will not function as such.

Comment: You just need one PictureBox/Panel to draw everything. First draw both images side by side where the width of each image equal 1/2 the width of the canvas. Then draw the line over.

Comment: @TroyMac1ure the image using usual upload code  `pictureBoxLeft.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/RPC1940/Pictures/500px.jpg");
pictureBoxRight.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/RPC1940/Pictures/500px2.png"); `


@JQSOFT im using 2 picturebox because in the future each pictureboxes will be customizable so each of that can be rotated and changed. but please tell me more detail about that half canvas method.

Comment: An edit to above. You can have a transparent picturebox over another, but only it's parent. Since 2 panels cannot be it's parent it will only show the line over one of them. This could be used with JQSOFT's method above if the line needs to be constantly moved, otherwise draw it right onto the canvas after painting the images on.

Comment: @TroyMac1ure I still not understand yet how parent code works. I tried using that to the table which the 2 pictureboxes docked and the error is gone but cannot draw the line. if the parent code erased, the error is back but can draw the lines

Comment: You still can do all of that using a single drawing canvas. Including (as I understand from the screenshots) rotating the images, line x, y offset.

Comment: Do you have a loop in your code that is locking up your UI? You will need to post your code for that issue.

Comment: Nevermind. tries to remake the program in different save file with exact same code and the error is gone. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main code, load the images into memory. This method keeps the files locked which can be avoided by loading them into a memorystream if desired.

```
    Image image1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/RPC1940/Pictures/500px.jpg");
    Image image2 = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/RPC1940/Pictures/500px2.jpg");
```

Then on the picturebox paint event draw the images onto the main canvas and paint your line over top as well. This doesn't take into account stretching, etc but should give you a start.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int halfWidth = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image1, new Rectangle(0, 0, halfWidth, pictureBox1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image2, new Rectangle(halfWidth + 1, 0, halfWidth, pictureBox1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 140, 140, 300, 300);
    }
```

Comment: It works but the blank error is back along with it. I've deleted the table & 2 picturebox only leaving the big one for this canvas.

Comment: The second image needs the same half width as well. Well done.